# Reduce resources consumed by aircrack-ng

Tags: aircrack-ng

I am trying to perform dictionary attack with aircrack-ng.
As soon as I start testing keys in the dictionary file, by executing this, you know, "famous" command: `aircrack-ng -w capture-01.cap`, my computer's fan goes crazy and about 30 seconds, the computer shut down due to overheating.
Overheating had never been a problem to my computer.
I guess, because aircrack-ng tests so many keys in every little amount of time, it actually consumes quite a lot of resources that my computer can't hold.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: a Google search turned this up as the top hit: https://github.com/Akash786mrn/wifite/issues/44

Comment: questions about how to resolve errors or malfunctions in programs is beyond the scope of this site and are more relevant to the developers of the program